# Is static class variable always initialized before a constructor of its static instance is called?

Tags: c++, static, initialization

Consider a situation like in the code below.

```cpp
// Foo.h
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        foos.emplace_back(this);
    }

private:
    static std::vector<Foo*> foos;
};
```

```cpp
// Foo.cpp
std::vector<Foo*> Foo::foos;
```

```cpp
// Bar.h
class Bar
{
private:
    static Foo foo;
};
```

```cpp
// Bar.cpp
Foo Bar::foo;
```

Being aware of Static Initialization Order Fiasco, can I assume that `Foo::foos` will always be initialized before `Bar::foo` constructor is called or is the order still unspecified?

[From what I gathered](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.start.init) it seems to me that it depends on types used, but in my case such an assumption is invalid since `std::vector` doesn't have a `constexpr` constructor so its initialization is performed during the *dynamic initialization* step of non-local variable initialization and the same applies to `Foo`. Is this true?

Comment: I don't think so. It is probably still UB ...

Comment: It is UB unless `Foo::foos` and `Bar:foo` are defined in the same compilation unit, in which case it is the order of definition.

Comment: Please explain what parts of the section you linked suggest that the order is specified.

Comment: @molbdnilo The section I linked doesn't suggest that the order is specified in my case, quite the contrary, which I pointed out in the question. If I understand correctly the order would be specified if `std::vector` fulfilled [requirement 2.2 of constant initialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.start.init#2.2).

Comment: The standard workaround for cases like this is to put the “early static variable” into a function (that returns a reference to it) so that it is initialized on first call.